# Do I add read committed after SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE?

Tags: t-sql, transaction, isolation-level

Inside a stored procedure, I have the following : ( sql server 2008 )

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
 BEGIN TRANSACTION getStuff
 BEGIN TRY 
    /*  some selects, updates, etc, etc. */
    ....
    COMMIT TRANSACTION getStuff
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH 
   ...
 END CATCH
```

Since this is transaction based, my thought was the rest of the database connections will not be affected by the SERIALIZABLE.

Do I need to implicitly set isolation level to read committed after my commit? Will this adversely effect other connections between my application server and database server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command is `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`, not `SERVER ISOLATION LEVEL`. It only changes the isolation level for the transaction scope.

Answer (score 5):

No you do not have to implicitly set isolation level back to read committed.

From books [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql).

> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or
>   trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object was invoked. For example, if
>   you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored
>   procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation
>   level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure
>   returns control to the batch.

Answer (score 3):

The command that you posted just run the transaction in the SP with `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`. Other connections will default to the default isolation level - read committed (unless specified a different isolation level explicitly).

There is an excellent series by Paul White - [SQL Server Isolation Levels : A Series](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels) which will help you understand in depth what different isolation levels mean and do when they are used.